# Argo Workflows pods missing cpu/memory resources

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, argo-workflows, argoproj

I'm running into a missing resources issue when submitting a `Workflow`. The Kubernetes namespace `my-namespace` has a quota enabled, and for whatever reason the pods being created after submitting the workflow are failing with:

```
pods "hello" is forbidden: failed quota: team: must specify limits.cpu,limits.memory,requests.cpu,requests.memory
```

I'm submitting the following `Workflow`,

```
apiVersion: "argoproj.io/v1alpha1"
kind: "Workflow"
metadata:
  name: "hello"
  namespace: "my-namespace"
spec:
  entrypoint: "main"
  templates:
  - name: "main"
    container:
      image: "docker/whalesay"
      resources:
        requests:
          memory: 0
          cpu: 0
        limits:
          memory: "128Mi"
          cpu: "250m"
```

Argo is running on Kubernetes 1.19.6 and was deployed with the [official Helm chart](https://github.com/argoproj/argo-helm) version 0.16.10. Here are my Helm values:

```
controller:
  workflowNamespaces:
  - "my-namespace"
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 0
      cpu: 0
    limits:
      memory: 500Mi
      cpu: 0.5
  pdb:
    enabled: true
  # See https://argoproj.github.io/argo-workflows/workflow-executors/
  # docker container runtime is not present in the TKGI clusters
  containerRuntimeExecutor: "k8sapi"
workflow:
  namespace: "my-namespace"
  serviceAccount:
    create: true
  rbac:
    create: true
server:
  replicas: 2
  secure: false
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 0
      cpu: 0
    limits:
      memory: 500Mi
      cpu: 0.5
  pdb:
    enabled: true
executer:
  resources:
    requests:
      memory: 0
      cpu: 0
    limits:
      memory: 500Mi
      cpu: 0.5
```

Any ideas on what I may be missing? Thanks, Weldon

Update 1: I tried another namespace without quotas enabled and got past the missing resources issue. However I now see: `Failed to establish pod watch: timed out waiting for the condition`. Here's what the `spec` looks like for this pod. You can see the `wait` container is missing `resources`. This is the container causing the issue reported by this question.

```
spec:
  containers:
  - command:
    - argoexec
    - wait
    env:
    - name: ARGO_POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          apiVersion: v1
          fieldPath: metadata.name
    - name: ARGO_CONTAINER_RUNTIME_EXECUTOR
      value: k8sapi
    image: argoproj/argoexec:v2.12.5
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: wait
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /argo/podmetadata
      name: podmetadata
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: default-token-v4jlb
      readOnly: true
  - image: docker/whalesay
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: main
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 250m
        memory: 128Mi
      requests:
        cpu: "0"
        memory: "0"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try deploying the workflow on another namespace if you can, and verify if it's working or not.

if you can try with removing the quota for respective namespace.

instead of quota you can also use the

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: LimitRange
metadata:
  name: default-limit-range
spec:
  limits:
  - default:
      memory: 512Mi
      cpu: 250m
    defaultRequest:
      cpu: 50m
      memory: 64Mi
    type: Container
```

so any container have not resource request, limit mentioned that will get this default config of 50m CPU & 64 Mi Memory.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/limit-range/

Comment: That would probably work, but it's not quite the solution I'm looking for. Switching to a namespace without a quota gets me past this issue, but now seeing `Failed to establish pod watch: timed out waiting for the condition`. I'm going to update the question with some more detail.

Comment: I added an `Update 1` to my question with more details on which container is missing resources. Ideally there would be a Helm property to define the resources, but maybe it's not currently possible?

Comment: in helm you can provide the resource block and ideally it should has to work when we apply the helm.

Comment: I realized this week after looking at the configmap template that I had misspelled `executor`. In my description it was `executer`. After making that change everything worked as expected.

Comment: I just accepted this answer because there have been similar situations since where a `LimitRange` was required. In my specific case there was a typo, but I think a limit range can be a good solution as a fallback.